jQuery select2 inside a responsive table
I am using select2 inside a responsive table and it's adding unnecessary horizontal scrollbar to the page. If the select element is visible on page load, then the scroll bar doesn’t appear. However, if the select element is not visible on page load (i.e. it is hidden because the table is responsive) then this scroll bar appears. Any idea?
I tried applying the select2 only to the select element which is in the first column (i.e. inside the first TD) and the scroll bar doesn't appear.
When I apply select2 to the one in the last column then the scroll bar appears. I am not talking about the table scroll bar it's the page scroll bar.

Please visit [ask]. Then post a [mcve] using the [<>] snippet editor

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
